# Clicking on Inbox or Reputation box when site is 'Read only mode' gives messages which are hard to read due to scrolling issues

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, maintenance

When the site is in read-only mode and you go to someone or your network profile and click on the inbox you get something like this:

[image]

[image]

It is too tough to read the message. Scrolling doesn't work with the keyboard, so you can't even read the message. Can this be changed to giving a banner showing that site is in 'read-only mode' or either asking to log in or either something like this

[image]

Tested on Chrome, Windows 10 and Chrome, Windows 7. The above screenshots are of Windows 10, Chrome.